# How to hide the profile menu on the app bar without using a custom layout?

Tags: react-admin

I need to put the logout button instead the profile menu on the app bar.

I'm taking about this:

[image]

I was looking in the react-admin documentation but i didn't found something clear without use a custom layout with a custom appbar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is documented in the [theming section](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html#using-a-custom-layout) of the react-admin documentation:

```
import { AppBar, UserMenu, MenuItemLink } from 'react-admin';
import SettingsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Settings';

const MyUserMenu = props => (
    <UserMenu {...props}>
        <MenuItemLink
            to="/configuration"
            primaryText="Configuration"
            leftIcon={<SettingsIcon />}
        />
    </UserMenu>
);

const MyAppBar = props => <AppBar {...props} userMenu={<MyUserMenu />} />;

const MyLayout = props => <Layout {...props} appBar={MyAppBar} />;
```

Comment: Thank you!
I only checked the firtst part of the [theming section](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html), sorry for that, was my bad.

Comment: Any idea to remove logout button ?

Comment: I have added UserMenu, but still there is a menu with usericon and logout shows up on clicking How to remove logout button. How to remove the usericon or the default usermenu ?